# How to rotate a mesh until one of its vertices touches a face?

Tags: vertices, transforms, faces, snapping

How do I rotate a mesh so that one of its vertices snaps to/touches a face? I want to have it end up looking like something in the image. The "mesh" I'm referring to is the selected parts. I want to snap rotate the entire "mesh" until the active vertex touches that face on the bottom. I tried using Face Project and Face Nearest. Face Project doesn't actually snap it but instead sways rotation as I move the mouse across face. Face Nearest doesn't keep the shape of the "mesh" and deforms it entirely. [image: Vertex touching face]

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann: this is my comment to your comment on the deleted post: i just tried that out because i couldn't believe that snapping is so bad as you wrote, and my snapping settings were this:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXzwt.png and it rotated/snapped perfectly. I zoomed in full 4x.  What do i have to do to reproduce your snapping failure?

Comment: @Chris does the vertex sit on $z = 0$ when you snap to the default plane spawned on world origin? My experience is Blender doesn't have a good rotational snapping option like the one OP requests, unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: not at zero, but i think at the point where is should be, shouldn't it? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOA3f.png

Comment: @Chris for an accurate test, position the plane at $z=0$, then rotate the geometry, with one vertex active, snapping to the plane. The target is to rotate in such a way, that this vertex lies on a plane **exactly** - which you would measure by confirming the $z$ of the active vertex equals exactly $0$. If you eye-ball it, or position a plane arbitrarily, it's harder to spot the inaccuracy.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: that's what i did. Just my origin of that vehicle isn't zero - but i am on 4.2 alpha - maybe they fixed it? or i am doing something "wrong"

Comment: @Chris and you got vertex $z = 0$? as for αlpha - you could test the same workflow on earlier versions.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: yep, a -0 but i think that's ok. After i set the vehicles origin to 0,0,0

Comment: @Chris Sorry for answering late, your tag didn't work ;) First of all, my snapping failure was produced by the settings in the deleted answer, snapping to _Edge Perpendicular_ with active vertex in _Edit Mode_. But no matter what, this did not work for ages. Here _Object Mode_ with face snap like you did: [snap with rotate (object)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Zbd.gif) and _Edit Mode_: [snap with rotate (edit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf1XP.gif) - both times it rotates basically free although snapped to the face at all times (see circle at cursor). Did not work with vehicle at 0,0,0 either.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: i think i got it, why mine work - i used 3d cursor as pivot point

Comment: @Chris I did this with the 3D cursor in _Edit Mode_ as well. So you want to say, no matter where on the face you move the cursor, it snaps to the correct position? The vertices of these handle parts directly on the face while nobody else gets this result? That's strange.

Comment: with Blender 4.2 alpha on a Mac with apple silicon - i would say yes. one more thing, i used R X ....if i just use R it won't work. Not on the whole face, but on the right side (so 50%)

Comment: @Chris I use `R` `Y` because my object is oriented differently, but anyway, this is 4.2 alpha, using 3D cursor as pivot point, snapped to the face the whole time as the circle indicates, still not snapping to a defined static position: [rotating in object mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOIxv.gif) or here in _Edit Mode_ with an active vertex to use _Snap with Active_ to ensure the vertex snaps to the face: [rotating in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpnRL.gif). The circle shows, it is snapped all the time. It also does not matter if the magnet is enabled or if I snap with holding `Ctrl`.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady So you did not get it to work either? Or am I the only one now?

Comment: i can offer to check whether it works with your blend file, if u want

Comment: @Chris At least we could check then if it's a matter of Mac or Windows :D file: [snap_rotate.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hgva8Xlix7kamkbWBg_pcJnoEjo_WkRl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151636/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-chris).

Answer (score 1):

Closest I got to was just checking the 'affect rotation' box in the Snap transform settings.[image: Snap Transform] I then positioned the 3D cursor on the correct pivot point, and set the 'Transform Pivot Point' to '3D Cursor' [image: Transform Pivot Point 3D Cursor]

This allowed me to align the rotation to the plane, however what point on the plane was still down to just mouse position. I think in order to stop the rotation at the intersection of the rotated geometry and the plane, or to calculate the height of the floor/angle of the surface would require some custom scripts.

Alternatively you could make the pivot point the handle of the wagon, and rotate until the wheels are where you need them. I suppose thats the same problem in reverse

Comment: This is the exact same thing I did. That's why it's a problem.